# What is the fastest way to compile a phonegap code?

Tags: phonegap-build, devextreme

Whenever I test for any change in my code (add an 'console.log' for example) involving a phonegap command, I need make the process of use Visual Studio to create the .zip, upload it on phonegap site, generate a .apk, install it in the emulator, open inspect chrome and then test it?
Or is there a faster alternative?

Comment: If you only need to test the UI(user interface), you can test in the browser - you do not need to go through the entire cycle. If you are using, Phonegap build, try hydration. With hydration you can test in the device, and no need to install. There is also an online console (debugging) via Wienre that you can use. *Hydration and Debugging* options you can turn on when you first upload the APP or under *settings*

Answer (score 0):

In you tags you mentioned DevExtreme.

With DevExtreme product, if you need to test you device-specific code, you can use [DevExtreme Courier apps](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/VS_Integration/Simulation_Tools/#Run_on_Device), which are available for iOS, Android and Windows Phone, or just [run app in your device browser](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/VS_Integration/Simulation_Tools/#Run_in_Device_Browser) by scanning QR-code (but this way no any PhoneGap plugins will be available)

Or, if you need to test just UI, you can run your app in your device browser or use [build-in simulator](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/VS_Integration/Simulation_Tools/#Use_Simulator) which runs in most of browsers and let you test any non-device specific features.